# How to copy csv line with extra delimiter to another file while loading to MySQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I am working on a tricky code. The client wants to load the data to MySQL but excluding the lines which have extra delimiters or have carriage return issues. I was able to complete the loading part using the below code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


import string
import csv
import mysql.connector
import re


# In[2]:


mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="password",autocommit=True)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()


# In[3]:


sql_str=''
sql_str1=''
placeholder=''
field_name=[]
line=1
i_holder=0
file_name=input("\nFile name with extension:")
delimiter_=input('\nDelimiter used:')
textquali=input('\nText Qualifier used Press Enter if no qualifier:')


# In[4]:


mycursor.execute("drop table if exists  rd.pbc_gl_sigline_src")
#r"C:\Users\rcsid\Documents\Office Programs\Working prog\MOCK_DATA.csv"
#re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]\n\.', '_', row)
reader = csv.DictReader(open(file_name,encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore'), delimiter=delimiter_,quotechar=textquali)
rowHeaders = reader.fieldnames
#print(rowHeaders)
for i in rowHeaders:
    field_name.append(re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '_', i))
#print(field_name)
#print(f'''create table rd.data_with_header ( {" varchar(100), ".join(field_name)} varchar(100))''')
sql_str=f'''create table rd.pbc_gl_sigline_src ( {" varchar(250), ".join(field_name)} varchar(100))'''
mycursor.execute(sql_str)
placeholders=", ".join(['%s']*len(field_name))
sql_str1=f"""insert into rd.pbc_gl_sigline_src values ({placeholders})"""
for row in reader:
    if any(val is None for val in row.values()):
        print(row)
    line=line+1
    #print(row)
    print(line)
    mycursor.execute(sql_str1,tuple(row.values()))
print("Loaded to pbc_gl_sigline_src")

#if any(val in (None, "") for val in row.itervalues()):

# In[ ]:
```

In the above code, Python is loading the data and printing the lines which have carriage return issue(line moved to next line). The trouble is I am not able to print the lines with extra delimiters in them. The following error is getting generated:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\conversion.py", line 179, in to_mysql
    return getattr(self, "_{0}_to_mysql".format(type_name))(value)
AttributeError: 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_list_to_mysql'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 425, in _process_params
    res = [to_mysql(i) for i in res]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 425, in <listcomp>
    res = [to_mysql(i) for i in res]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\conversion.py", line 182, in to_mysql
    "MySQL type".format(type_name))
TypeError: Python 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SingleLineLoader_WithHeader_v3_dictwrite_notfinal.py", line 61, in <module>
    mycursor.execute(sql_str1,tuple(row.values()))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 547, in execute
    psub = _ParamSubstitutor(self._process_params(params))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 430, in _process_params
    "Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % err)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

If there are not extra delimiters then the code is working fine and printing the lines with the carriage return lines.
My main job is to load the lines which are ok and copy the problematic lines to a new file where the client can have a look at them . The client would just want to run the code on the data which they will get from another client. So there are two problems here. First is excluding the problematic lines from getting loaded and second copying them to another file. Is there any try/except method or any workaround for this? I am grateful for your help.

Also, if the lines do not get excluded during loading the data and gets loaded  but gets copied to a new file that would also work. The client can exclude those lines from the database.

Comment: *load the data to MySQL but excluding the lines which have extra delimiters or have carriage return issues* MySQL can do this without python's help. Use LOAD DATA IGNORE, load each line into one user-defined variable, then check and parse it to table's columns. If line format is distinguished as incorrect then the value which exists in the table with guarantee should be assigned to some column which is unique (PK primarily), this value may be provided in separate user-defined variable.

Comment: hi, can you elaborate a bit more on this . specially the part 'parse it to table's columns'

Comment: Also, the client does not want to work on MySQL, they pretty much want a code which will load everything for them without them accessing the data. If you notice the code sets the header and all by itself so that the client does not have to access the data as the datasets are large

Comment: *can you elaborate a bit more on this . specially the part 'parse it to table's columns'* [LOAD DATA INFILE / Input Preprocessing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-input-preprocessing). *the client does not want to work on MySQL, they pretty much want a code which will load everything for them without them accessing the data.* I do not use python and cannot help you, sorry.